# How do I destroy a Tk window after opening another with a function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to open a whole new file with a different GUI after the user presses the Login button, but I cant seem to destroy the main Tk window when they click it.

```py
    def __init__(self, master=None): #This is how I initialized the TK window
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,master)
        m_login = tkinter.Button(text="Login",bg="#1e1e1e",foreground="#b4b4b4",width=10,command=self.login)
    def login(self):
        os.startfile('maingui.py')
        self.tkinter.destroy() #Idk what goes here
```

Comment: Use `self.destroy()`

Comment: `os.startfile('maingui.py')` may works on your computer but may not work on others - ie. users may not have assigned `.py` to Python, `os.startfile` doesn't exist on Linux. I would rather `import maingui` and  run class/function from this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.destroy
```

works in most cases, but I found that importing the class and function then closing the first one seemed to work best.